# Why does my web-app work offline in Firefox, but not on iPad?

Tags: offline

I recently wrote a few scripts for Javascript which I am trying to run as a native app on my iPad in offline mode.

The scripts do nothing complex, simply run off a bunch of prompts and generate a document.write() based on the information the user has entered.

So I set up my own little website to host the scripts on and went about setting up an application cache. I am new to this sort of thing however from what I gather, I have followed instructions correctly. To set up my app cache, I did the following:

Added the following two lines to my .htaccess file:
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
AddType text/manifest .manifest

Made a new file called "generator.manifest", which has the following lines:
CACHE MANIFEST
generator.html
answergenerator.js

And added in to my generator.html file:

Apart from a few functions used to prompt some iOS features, all I have in my generator.html file is this:

along with the other stock standard html tags.

That is my appcache setup. The generator.manifest file is in the exact same directory as the generator.html file.

When I enter Firefox and go to my site, I can run the script, allow it to cache files for offline usage (Firefox comes up with a prompt), and then run the script in offline mode.

HOWEVER, whenever I try to do this on my iPad (4.2.1), I simply get the error: "Generator could not be opened because it is not connected to the Internet."

Where have I gone wrong? Can someone help me fix this please?

A huge thanks in advance,
Haz.

Comment: when i say added this to my generator.html file, i mean this: <*html manifest="generator.manifest">

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047631/why-might-cache-manifest-fail-to-get-mobile-safari-to-cache-site-while-working-as). iOS does seem to have some issues. I found that I had to power cycle my iPad (in addition to clearing open Safari's) before it would recognize the appcache.